# PHP how to call function onClick

Tags: php, javascript

I need to call this function Hello() before load the page, what happen is : function is done but location.href don't work,    i need it to work how?

```
<input type=button onClick="return Hello(this);location.href='go.php?f_name=<?php echo             $_POST['f_name']; ?>&job=<?php echo $_POST['job']; ?>&id_up=<?php echo $count1;?>'" value='Save'>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're returning the result of `Hello()` from the `onclick` event. Thus, anything thereafter is never called. Remove `return`, and it should function correctly:

```
<input type=button onClick="Hello(this);location.href='go.php?f_name=<?php echo             $_POST['f_name']; ?>&job=<?php echo $_POST['job']; ?>&id_up=<?php echo $count1;?>'" value='Save'>
```

Comment: i try it but when function return false it should stay on same page 
but what happen is function is done and page is load,it should not load page if function return false

Comment: i use this function

<script language='JavaScript' type='text/JavaScript'>
function Hello() {
if((document.f1.f_name.value=='')||(document.f1.job.value==''))
  {
  alert('Please fill all fields');
  return false;
  }   
if ((1>'<?php echo $valid_m ?>'))
{ alert('you should <?php echo $valid_m ?>, upload your sick leave letter'); return false; }
  
}
</script>

Answer (score 0):

```
i try it but when function return false it should stay on same page
```

**edit :**

```
<?php
$_POST['f_name']    = 'stack';
$_POST['job']       = 'over';
$count1             = 'flow';
$valid_m            = 10;
?>
<script language='JavaScript' type='text/JavaScript'>
function Hello() 
{
    if ((document.f1.f_name.value == '') || (document.f1.job.value == '')) {
        alert('Please fill all fields');
        return false;
    }
    if ((1 > '<?php echo $valid_m ?>')) {
        alert('you should <?php echo $valid_m ?>, upload your sick leave letter');
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
</script>
<input type=button onClick="if(Hello(this)) location.href='go.php?f_name=<?php echo $_POST['f_name']; ?>&job=<?php echo $_POST['job']; ?>&id_up=<?php echo $count1;?>'" value='Save'>
```

Comment: @user1562744 : i edit my answer , please check it,hope it helps.

Comment: i add else after seconed if and it's work fine

else{return true;}  so it's work when if result is true ^_^